# conditional where clause in sql for date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which has two parameters:

```
@PublishedFrom SMALLDATETIME = NULL,
@PublishedDeadline SMALLDATETIME = NULL
```

I want that when `PublishedDeadline` is null then `WHERE` condition should have:

```
WHERE (dbo.Vacancies.StartDate >= @PublishedFrom 
       OR @PublishedFrom IS NULL)
```

but if `PublishedDeadline` is not empty then `WHERE` clause should be like

```
WHERE v.startdate <= @PublishedDeadline 
  and @PublishedFrom <= v.EndDate
```

how can i apply conditional where clause in SQL?

Please suggest

Answer (score 4):

The following should work for you:

```
WHERE (PublishedDeadline IS NULL 
       AND (
            dbo.Vacancies.StartDate >= @PublishedFrom 
            OR @PublishedFrom IS NULL
       ) OR (
        PublishedDeadline IS NOT NULL 
        AND v.startdate <= @PublishedDeadline 
        AND @PublishedFrom <= v.EndDate
       )
```

just combine `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` condition with other conditions

Comment: do i need to add check for Publishedfrom is not null in second part after OR ?

Comment: That depends on how do you want the query to behave. Without all the info about your intentions, I can't answer this questions. But, I can say, that comparison like `NULL <= something` will give you `NULL` result.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow If you not sure, just add `AND PublishedFrom IS NOT NULL` after `PublishedDeadline IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working in Stored Procedures, you might want to have a more verbose, more easily readable query

```
if (@PublishedDeadline is NULL)
BEGIN
   Select * from dbo.Vacancies
   WHERE (dbo.Vacancies.StartDate >= @PublishedFrom 
   OR @PublishedFrom IS NULL)
END
else
BEGIN
   Select * from dbo.Vacancies
   WHERE v.startdate <= @PublishedDeadline 
    and @PublishedFrom <= v.EndDate
END
```